# Which classes of subsets are absolute under forcing?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, forcing

Let $X$ be a ‘definable’ Polish space (in the day-to-day, not necessarily the set-theoretic sense, though possible the latter generalises this). Consider a complexity class $\Gamma(X)$ of subsets of $X$, such as the open, closed, $\mathbf{\Pi}^{0}_{2}$, $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{1}_{1}$, measurable, meagre, etc. sets. Are there known results, which say $\Gamma(X)$ remains unchanged under forcing? In particular, I want to know if in general the class of $\mathbf{\Pi}^{0}_{2}$-subsets remains unchanged under forcing extensions.

**EDIT.** I apologise for the unclarity. There are indeed many versions of this question. What I concretely need is the following: Let $\mathbb{V}\models\mathrm{ZFC}$ and $\mathbb{V}[G]$ be a forcing extension. Let $X$ be parameter-definable in $\mathbb{V}$ say by $X=\{x\mid\phi(x,a)\}$ where $a\in\mathbb{V}$. Suppose $A\subseteq X$ is formula definable in $\mathbb{V}$ via $A=\{x\in X\mid \psi(x)^{X}\}$. And assume $\psi$ is of logical complexity $\Gamma$, so that $A\in\Gamma(X)$ (in $\mathbb{V}$). Now let $X':=\{x\in\mathbb{V}[G]\mid\mathbb{V}[G]\models\phi(x,a)\}$ and $A':=\{x\in X'\mid \psi(x)^{X'}\}$. Clearly, $A'\in\Gamma(X')$ in $\mathbb{V}[G]$. But could the complexity reduce? That is, if $\Gamma'\subset\Gamma$ is strictly, and $(A\notin\Gamma'(X))^{\mathbb{V}}$, could it hold that $(A'\in\Gamma'(X'))^{\mathbb{V}[G]}$? Concretely I'm concerned with the case of something like $\Gamma=\mathbf{\Pi}^{1}_{3}$ and $\Gamma'=\mathbf{\Pi}^{0}_{2}$.

Comment: What does it mean for $\Gamma(X)$ to be "unchanged under forcing"?  Certainly this won't be literally true, since forcing could change $X$ itself.

Comment: If $\mathbb{V}\models\mathrm{ZFC}$ and $\mathbb{V}[G]$ is a forcing extension, and if $X$ is parameter-definable in $\mathbb{V}$ say by $X=\{x\mid\phi(x,a)\}$ where $a\in\mathbb{V}$, then clearly $\Gamma(X)^{\mathbb{V}[G]}\cap\mathbb{V}\supseteq\Gamma(X)^{\mathbb{V}}$. I want to know under what conditions equality always holds.

Comment: That "clearly" statement is false.  For instance, if $\Gamma(X)$ is the set of open subsets of $X$, then $\Gamma(X)^{\mathbb{V}[G]}\cap\mathbb{V}$ could well be empty since $X^{\mathbb{V}}$ may have empty interior in $X^{\mathbb{V}[G]}$.

Comment: You're right. I've clarified above.

Comment: Incidentally, you may find [this paper of Zapletal](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/zapletal/files/interpretations2.pdf) interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Again, let's take $X=\omega^\omega$ for simplicity.

You're basically asking whether - for example - a "${\bf \Pi^1_3}$-code" could describe a properly ${\bf \Pi^1_3}$ set in $V$ but a much simpler (say, ${\bf \Pi^0_2}$) set in $V[G]$.

The answer is **yes**. For a concrete example, the set $S$ of nonconstructible reals is "uniformly" ${\bf \Pi^1_2}$ ($x$ is nonconstructible if *for every* countable $\omega$-model of ZFC+V=L containing $x$, *there is* a descending sequence in the ordinals of that model). But its *optimal* complexity can vary wildly:

- If $V=L$ then $S=\emptyset$ and hence is ${\bf \Delta^0_0}$. *(Note that "$S=\emptyset$" is $\Pi^1_3$ and so Shoenfield absoluteness doesn't apply to it.)*
- If $\omega_1^L$ is countable, then $S$ is cocountable and hence ${\bf \Pi^0_2}$ - and since $S$ is codense, by the Baire category theorem it's not ${\bf \Sigma^0_2}$. *Note that the ${\bf \Pi^0_2}$-code for $S$ in such a model will not itself be an element of $L$, so this doesn't contradict Shoenfield either.*
- And finally, if I recall correctly it's possible for $S$ to achieve the upper bound of "properly ${\bf \Pi^1_2}$," although this is harder to show *(and I might be misremembering, I'm rather tired).*

Going a bit further up, though, and being a bit less natural, we can get an easy-to-verify counterexample: consider $$\{x\in\omega^\omega:(\mathbb{R}^L=\mathbb{R})\wedge\psi(x)\},$$ where $\psi(x)$ is some formula which ZFC-provably defines a ${\bf \Pi^1_3}$-complete set. This set's obvious definition is $\Pi^1_3$ *("$\mathbb{R}^L=\mathbb{R}$" is already $\Pi^1_3$)*; however, in some models (namely, if $\mathbb{R}\not=\mathbb{R}^L$) it's empty and hence ${\bf \Delta^0_0}$ while in other models (namely, if $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^L$) it's ${\bf \Pi^1_3}$-complete. And this is at the specific level you ask about.

(Note that this specific trick won't work to get a $\Pi^1_2$ example - Shoenfield would prevent that.)

---

The problem is that the phrase

> $\Gamma(X)$ remains unchanged under forcing

is very unclear. Remember that forcing - even very nice forcing - can change $X$ itself (e.g. Cohen forcing "adds points to $\mathbb{R}$").

The simplest nontrivial way to express your question, I think, is:

> Suppose we have a formula $\varphi$ defining a subset of $\omega^\omega$ (focusing on this choice of $X$ for simplicity). Under what conditions do we have $$\varphi^{V[G]}\cap V=\varphi^V$$ for every generic extension $V[G]$ of $V$?

That is, we allow $\varphi$ to "gain points" since the underlying space itself gains points, but we require that $\varphi$ not "change its mind."

In this case, the usual absoluteness principles have something to say. For example, [**Shoenfield absoluteness**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield's_absoluteness_theorem) - which is roughly [the extent of absoluteness which ZFC alone provides us, but not the limit of possible absoluteness](https://mathoverflow.net/a/71973/8133) - tells us that the above equation holds whenever $\varphi$ is $\Pi^1_2$ with real parameters (or $\Sigma^1_2$ with real parameters). Additional set-theoretic assumptions get more absoluteness of course. And certainly this implies that $\Pi^0_2$ sets (or rather, $\Pi^0_2$ *definitions* - we're really looking at the precise definition, not just the bare set itself) have the "preservation" property above.

We can also ask when a formula retains a certain property, e.g.:

> Suppose $\varphi$ is a formula defining a subset of $\omega^\omega$ and $P$ is some property (e.g. measurability, $\Sigma^0_1$-ness, ...). When can we conclude that $$V[G]\models P(\varphi^{V[G]})\quad\iff V\models P(\varphi^V)$$ for every generic extension $V[G]$ of $V$?

Again, the approach is basically syntactic: look at the complexity of $P$ and $\varphi$, and see whether the current set-theoretic axioms allow that sort of absoluteness. For a negative example, we can have an open set become properly $\Sigma^1_{17}$ in a generic extension: letting $\varphi(x)$ be the formula "either $\mathbb{R}^V=\mathbb{R}^L$ or $\psi(x)$," where $\psi$ is a ZFC-provably-$\Sigma^1_{17}$-complete formula, we get that $\varphi^L$ is open (namely, $\varphi^L=\mathbb{R}^L$) but $\varphi^{L[G]}$ is $\Sigma^1_{17}$-complete if $L[G]$ has a non-constructible real.

The issue here is that $\varphi$ is so complicated that the principle "$\varphi$ is open" is **not susceptible to Shoenfield absoluteness**. On the other hand, it *is* absolute provided we have enough large cardinals in the universe (and remember, to forestall worry, that enough large cardinals do prevent $V=L$). 
 So the complexity of $\varphi$ itself, as well as the property $P$ in question, plays into the problem.

---

However, I'm not sure this is what you really want, since you seem to be talking about the *class of sets itself* being unchanged. In general this is something we can't ever hope for. For example, let $G\in 2^\omega$ be a Cohen real over $V$ and consider the set $$S_G=\{f\in\omega^\omega: f(1)=G(f(0))\}.$$ That is, an element $f$ of $S_G$ tells us one bit of  $G$: look at the first coordinate of $f$ to determine what bit of $G$ the real $f$ is trying to tell us, and at the second coordinate of $f$ to determine what the value of that bit of $G$ is. The point is that even though $S_G$ is open we know that $S_G\cap V$ is **not in $V$**, since otherwise we could determine $G$ in $V$ *(we'd have $G(n)=0\iff (n,0,0,0,...)\in S_G$)*; so I see no sense at all in which the class of opens of $V[G]$ is the same as the class of opens of $V[G]$.

Answer (score 1):

Shoenfield's absoluteness may be what you're looking for, but stronger and stronger absoluteness results require stronger and stronger assumptions.  Consider this pre-print: https://www.math.uci.edu/~twilson/papers/generic-absoluteness.pdf.